# Check if control can be checked?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checked

Is there a way to check for and set the Checked attribute for an unspecified Windows Control that supports it?

Of course, there's the brute-force method:

```
If TypeOf (control) Is Windows.Forms.CheckBox Then
    Dim chk As Windows.Forms.CheckBox = control
    chk.Checked = Boolean.Parse(sText)
ElseIf TypeOf (control) Is Windows.Forms.RadioButton Then
    Dim rdo As Windows.Forms.RadioButton = control
    rdo.Checked = Boolean.Parse(sText)
ElseIf TypeOf (control) Is Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker Then
    Dim dte As Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker = control
    dte.Checked = Boolean.Parse(sText)
etc...
```

However, I do find that ugly, and there may be controls that I'll miss.

There doesn't appear to be a superclass, even for `CheckBox` and `RadioButton`, that support the attribute. Also, attempting to simply set `control.Checked` won't compile.

If you're curious what I'm up to, I'm looking to create a general purpose table that will store a default value for a named Control.

Comment: It's expensive and maybe even incorrect. For example the `DateTimePicker` has also a property [`ShowCheckBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.showcheckbox(v=vs.80).aspx). I would use your "ugly" approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to check the existence of any property called `Checked`, then you need to use reflection:

```
control.GetType().GetProperty("Checked") IsNot Nothing
```

(Note that this will throw an exception if `Checked` is overloaded.)

But do you really only want to save the `Checked` property of a `DateTimePicker`? It seems like you're looking for a list:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly CheckableTypes() As New HashSet(Of Type)({
    GetType(CheckBox), GetType(RadioButton), ...
})
...
If CheckableTypes.Contains(control.GetType()) Then
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I am confused.

Comment: The problem with the list is that you'll still need to cast the control to set the `Checked` attribute - attempting to use simply `control.Checked` won't compile. I realise I didn't include that aspect of the problem explicitly in my question - will fix.

Comment: Although I suppose you could just cast the control as an `Object`...might that create performance issues?

Comment: @Hannele: You can set that using reflection, then. I'll add that in six hours :)